# Add node refreshes view

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, view

I want to have a view of nodes, and above it, an add new node form, so its really easy to build a list (lets say a shopping list).

When i submit the form, i'd like it to refresh the view through ajax to include the new node.

What's the best way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got quite the set of requirements here. I'm going to assume you know how to build a view. Use a page output.

Create the form using Drupal forms api. Set up an autocomplete field and have your submit handler set a value in one of the fields in the node.  Put this form in a block ( [How to allow multiple blocks in a module of Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585912/how-to-allow-multiple-blocks-in-a-module-of-drupal/12590034#12590034) ) and display it on the top of the page this view outputs on.

For the ajax stuff I wrote a great blog post for my company outlining how to do that: http://clikfocus.com/blog/simple-ajax-example-drupal-6-and-7

In your callback run the function:

```
$view = views_embed_view('view_name', 'display_name', $args_array);
print $view;
```

Make sure you have view caching turned off and in you jQuery make sure to select the tag wrapping the view.

Your asking for a full module here so I can't write the whole thing right now but that should get you started.

Comment: :-) I've got a very specific requirement. That looks great danielson - I am fine with putting the elements together, its the connecting up form api with views i had no idea about. Thanks for the guidance, thats brilliant.

Comment: You bet. I found a cool tutorial on building a form autocomplete with ajax as well: http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-ajax-dropdown-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks - i've accepted this answer - i couldn't work out how to accept answers. oh yeah of course, its the big tick.